# Сложный запрос на 3 таблицы в Access

Tags: sql, запрос, ms-access

Есть три таблицы - *Таблица1*, *Таблица2*, *Таблица3*. Таблицы по структуре абсолютно одинаковые, скажем поля - *номер_задачи*(ключевое поле,совпадений нет), *заказчик, задача*.
*Таблица1* загружается каждый день из внешнего источника, в ней есть записи, которых нет в *Таблица2*, и в *Таблице2* есть записи которых нет в *Таблица1*, *Таблица2* - результат. *Таблица1* есть отсутствующие записи в *Таблица2* - новые задачи. В *Таблица2* есть записи, которых нет в *Таблица1* - решенные задачи.

**Требуется:** в *Таблица2* перенести решенные задачи в *Таблица3* (добавить к существующим) и добавить новые из *Таблица1* в *Таблица2*.

**"Если в Таблица2 нет записей из Таблица1, то добавляем их в Таблица2 и если в Таблица1 нет записей из Таблица2, то из Таблица2 переносим их в Таблица3"**

Comment: Вы хотите сделать это одним запросом? Тут логично делать два запроса `insert into from select`, сначала 2→3 и потом 1→2.

Comment: Я не могу понять как правильно оформить запрос именно, - "и если в Таблица1 нет записей из Таблица2, то из Таблица2 переносим их в Таблица3". Извините, просто в SQL совсем новичок.

Comment: На первую часть, если я правильно понял, то так: 
INSERT INTO Таблица2
SELECT Таблица1.*
FROM Таблица1 LEFT JOIN Таблица2 ON Таблица1.номер_задачи = Таблица2.номер_задачи
WHERE Таблица1.номер_задачи IS NULL

Comment: Не два запроса, а три. Ещё запрос на удаление из таблицы 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Таблица3] ([Номер задачи], [Заказчик], [Задача])
SELECT [Таблица2].[Номер задачи], [Таблица2].[Заказчик], [Таблица2].[Задача]
FROM [Таблица2]
LEFT JOIN [Таблица1] ON [Таблица2].[Номер задачи] =  [Таблица1].[Номер задачи]
WHERE  [Таблица1].[Номер задачи] IS NULL;

DELETE [Таблица2].*
FROM [Таблица2]
WHERE [Таблица2].[Номер задачи] IN (
                                   SELECT t2.[Номер задачи]
                                   FROM [Таблица2] AS t2 
                                   LEFT JOIN [Таблица1] ON t2.[Номер задачи] =  [Таблица1].[Номер задачи]
                                   WHERE  [Таблица1].[Номер задачи] IS NULL
                                   );

INSERT INTO [Таблица2] ([Номер задачи], [Заказчик], [Задача])
SELECT [Таблица1].[Номер задачи], [Таблица1].[Заказчик], [Таблица1].[Задача]
FROM [Таблица1]
LEFT JOIN [Таблица2] ON [Таблица2].[Номер задачи] =  [Таблица1].[Номер задачи]
WHERE  [Таблица2].[Номер задачи] IS NULL;
```

PS. Предполагается, что в таблице 2 НЕТ записей, присутствующих в таблице 3. Иначе необходимо дополнительное ограничение в первом запросе.

Comment: Вроде бы я понял, но при попытке повторить ваш запрос в базе Access выдает мне ошибку, - "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции SQL".

Comment: @Евгений Это ТРИ запроса. РАЗНЫХ запроса. И Вы должны создать ТРИ запроса. И выполнять их СТРОГО в указанном порядке.

Comment: Я понимаю, но запрос на удаление не желает работать.

Comment: Странно, но у меня получаются таблицы 1 и 2 абсолютно одинаковыми, теоретически это возможно, но не реально. А с удалением разобрался, это у меня руки кривые.

Comment: После выполнения запросов ТАК И ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ!!! Если в таблице 1 осталось что-то, чего нет в таблице 2 - неправильно отработало *Если в Таблица2 нет записей из Таблица1, то добавляем их в Таблица2*, если в таблице 2 осталось что-то, чего нет в таблице 1 - неправильно отработало *если в Таблица1 нет записей из Таблица2, то из Таблица2 переносим их в Таблица3*. Вывод - после обработки таблицы 1 и 2 должны быть идентичны.

Comment: Поясню принцип: сегодня в Таблица1 добавлено 10 записей, 10 задач, а из Таблица2 было закрыто 20 задач. Следовательно Таблица2 должна быть на 10 записей больше, в нее добавилось 10, но отняли 20. С Таблица3 проходит точно все отлично, туда добавляются все закрытые задачи.

Comment: *Следовательно Таблица2 должна быть на 10 записей больше, в нее добавилось 10, но отняли 20.* Вот у кого из нас проблемы с арифметикой?

Comment: Согласен, чуть спутал, на 10 меньше.

Comment: Ну да фиг бы с ею... что в ответе-то не нравится?